# create view - cross table causing myphpadmin to freeze

Tags: php, mysql, admin

I am quite new to MySQL and have got most things working with a little help. Today I seem to have made a more significant error and all my searching has not harvested an answer so car.

I created a cross table look up which seems to have ended up as a monster using create view. Now wrenching php admin my database  fails to load that table and sticks at the table before it.

I have tried to use drop and I have tried to use desk eternal to remove the data but it tells me the table does not exist.  When I run a show table query I can see it in the list.

Is there a way to get rid of this table?

Nik

Comment: To delete view you should use `drop view myview`, not `drop table myview`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try setting `$cfg['MaxExactCountViews'] = 0;` in phpmyadmin config, so it should unfreeze and show your tables.

As for getting rid of unwanted view, use `DROP VIEW my_view;` instead of `DROP TABLE my_view;`

Comment: Thanks, that has destressed me and got rid of the view (not a table)!